# Rascal pattern guards

Tags: pattern-matching, rascal

Does Rascal support pattern guards?

I'm trying to order subexpressions on build:

```
data Expr = and(Expr l, Expr r) | ... ;
Expr and(l, r) | r < l = and(r, l); // fictional syntax for "r < l" guard
```

If guards are unsupported, what's the best way to implement the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to simplify things I've used `int` as the type for `l` and `r` at first. What you want to do is something like the following:

```
rascal>data Expr = and(int l, int r);
ok

rascal>Expr and(int l, int r) = and(r,l) when r < l;
Expr (int, int): rascalfunction()

rascal>and(5,6);
Expr: and(5,6)

rascal>and(6,5);
Expr: and(5,6)
```

If you create a function with the same name as the constructor that returns the data type you are defining (e.g., `Expr`), this will allow you to do this kind of canonicalization. The `when` clause says to only apply the function when the condition matches. You could have a more complex condition, so if you had `Expr` instead as the type of the fields you could have a function like `eval` that actually evaluates an expression and returns a result. A partial example of this (which assumes you only have one level of nesting) is the following:

```
rascal>data Expr = number(int n) | and(Expr l, Expr r);
ok

rascal>int eval(number(int n)) = n;
int (Expr): rascalfunction()

rascal>Expr and(Expr l, Expr r) = and(r,l) when eval(r) < eval(l);
Expr (Expr, Expr): rascalfunction()

rascal>and(number(5),number(6));
Expr: and(
  number(5),
  number(6))

rascal>and(number(6),number(5));
Expr: and(
  number(5),
  number(6))
```

To use `when`, you need to use this expression form of a function, where you have an `=` sign and the return value. If you have a more complex computation in the canonicalization, you can instead do something like the following:

```
Expr and(int l, int r) { 
    if (r < l) {
        return and(r,l); 
    } else {
        fail; 
    }
}
```

This essentially does the same thing. If the condition is met, a new version of `and` is returned. If the condition is not met, `fail` is used to indicate that we don't actually want to apply this function, so the initial value will be returned:

```
rascal>and(5,6);
Expr: and(5,6)

rascal>and(6,5);
Expr: and(5,6)
```

Comment: I'd recommend always using `fail and;` instead of plain `fail` because `fail` is lexically scoped to the innermost fallible context (like a if-branch or the body of a for loop). In the case of `else` it's not necessary since the inner most fallible context is the function itself. `fail` with the label allows you to jump to an outer fallible context (in this case the `and` function).